# jquery get rel attribute and change it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys, I have the following code. It is basically a gallery script and when I mouse over the thumbnail, it will change the a bigger version of the thumbnail:

```
$.fn.CloudZoom = function (options) {
    try {
        document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);
    } catch (e) {}
    this.each(function () {
        var relOpts, opts;
        eval('var   a = {' + $(this).attr('rel') + '}');
        relOpts = a;
        if ($(this).is('.image')) {
            $(this).css({
                'position': 'relative',
                'display': 'block'
            });
            $('img', $(this)).css({
                'display': 'block'
            });
            if ($(this).parent().attr('id') != 'imageBox') {
                $(this).wrap('<div id="imageBox"></div>');
            }
            opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.CloudZoom.defaults, options);
            opts = $.extend({}, opts, relOpts);
            $(this).data('zoom', new CloudZoom($(this), opts));

        } else if ($(this).is('.thumbs')) {
            opts = $.extend({}, relOpts, options);
            $(this).data('relOpts', opts);
            $(this).bind('mouseenter click', $(this), function (event) {

                var data = event.data.data('relOpts');
                $('#' + 'mainImage').data('zoom').destroy();
                $('#' + 'mainImage').attr('href', event.data.attr('href'));
                // Change the small image to point to the new small image.
                $('#' + 'mainImage' + ' img').attr('src', data.thumby);
                $('#' + 'mainImage').CloudZoom();
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

The html reads as follows:

```
<li>
 <a href="gfx/boss_black.jpg" class="thumbs" rel="thumby:'gfx/boss_black.jpg'">
  <img src="gfx/boss-black-small.jpg">
 </a>
</li>
```

What I want to do is to write the `rel=""` tag without the "thumby".

I want the rel tag look like this:

```
rel="gfx/boss_black.jpg"
```

When I do this, the JS doesn't work anymore. How do I change the JS to simply get the "rel"?

Comment: Show us the JS as well, without it we have no idea.

Comment: Argh. Please don't use the rel attribute as "Attribute I can store arbitrary data in" it has a defined purpose!

Comment: You might want to use data-* attributes instead of rel, rel are for relationships, xfn, etc.

Comment: okay, I edited the post to include the js

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $('#' + 'mainImage' + ' img'),
    rel = img.parent().attr('rel'),
    thumby = rel.substr(8, rel.length - 9);

img.attr('src', thumby);
```

I would recommend storing the alternative `src` attribute in an attribute other than `rel` though. A [HTML5 data attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) would be a good candidate.

Also, that is a bizarre selector :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - there is a library called thumby that requires a special format for your rel tag that you do not want in your source.

I can see two possible soultions.

1. Try to execute the javascript that changes the rel tag before the thumby library is included. Javascript loads and executes in the order specified in your HTML document. Hopefully thumby will pick up the changed value, but the source html contains the old value.
2. Modify the thumby library - specifically the part that reads from rel, and maybe make it identify where to operate based on the class thumbs instead.

Comment: no, there is no library called thumby... thumby was called "smallImage" in the original gallery script, but I was changing it to thumby because I don't want to clutter up the rel"" tag too much

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<li>
 <a href="gfx/boss_black.jpg" class="thumbs">
  <img src="gfx/boss-black-small.jpg" rel="gfx/boss_black.jpg">
 </a>
</li>
```

...

```
$('.thumbs img').hover(
  function () {
    var r = $(this).attr('rel'), a = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr({'rel':a,'src':r});
  }, 
  function () {
    var r = $(this).attr('rel'), a = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr({'rel':a,'src':r});
  }
);
```